# Generate key using Pass Phrase or AesCryptoServiceProvider?

Tags: c#, cryptography, aescryptoserviceprovider

We using AES encryption to encrypt the data. Generating a key once in a year using some app(i.e console) so which way i have to choose to generate the key?

**1. Do we need to generate the key using the Pass Phrase method?**

**2. Or we have to choose the default generate key provided by AESCryptoServiceProvider?**

The below method uses Pass Phrase for generating the encryption.

Method 1:

```
private static readonly byte[] Salt = new byte[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 };

private static byte[] CreateKey(string password, int keyBytes = 32)
{
    const int Iterations = 300;
    var keyGenerator = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Salt, Iterations);
    return Convert.FromBase64String(keyGenerator.GetBytes(keyBytes));
}
```

The below method uses `AesCryptoServiceProvider` for generating Key and we didn't use Pass Phrase

Method 2:

```
var Key = default(string);

using (var provider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    provider.GenerateKey();
    Key = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(provider.Key);
}
```

Edit:

can we use this Random Number generation method?

```
public static byte[] RandomNumberGenerator()
{
  var rngBytes = new byte[32];
  using (RandomNumberGenerator objNumberGenerator = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
  {
    objNumberGenerator.GetBytes(rngBytes);
    return rngBytes;
  }

}
```

Comment: Here I have added two methods to generate the Key to store in DB, so i would like to know which one I have to choose among this methods or do we have any other way to generate the key?

Comment: Both methods are no good. You should generate the aes key using a secure random number generator. Possibly you encrypt the resulting key. This is not CC advice please read CC requirements.

Comment: @owlstead Can you please provide some link to read the CC req and also it would be great if you provide some sample code to generate using a secure random number generator.

Comment: Yes, that's an ok method to generate an AES key.