# Is AesCryptoServiceProvider.GenerateKey safe to use?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, encryption

[Maarten Bodewes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589259/maarten-bodewes)' comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288540/generate-key-using-pass-phrase-or-aescryptoserviceprovider), suggest that `AesCryptoServiceProvider.GenerateKey()` is unsafe to use for key generation.

We are currently using this method to generate cryptographically secure keys. Looking at the [underlying implementation on Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Security/Cryptography/AesCryptoServiceProvider.cs,3b0a43c99559a7f3), `GenerateKey()` calls `CryptGenKey` in the Win32 API.

I cannot find any resources that suggest `CryptGenKey` is compromised. Is it safe to use this implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GenerateKey` is perfectly safe, however the implementation on the linked question is not.

You can not call `Key = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(provider.Key);` to get a string from a random byte array, `GetString` can not be used on random binary data it is only to be used on a byte array generaded from calling `ASCII.GetBytes`. If you want to store the key in string format you need to use a formatting designed to store binary data like `Key = Convert.ToBase64String(provider.Key);`